# "No default constructor exists for class" if I want to construct a class with another one

Tags: c++

I have a class named `Ball` and I want to create a class `Particle` with, in its constructor, a `std::vector<Ball> particles`, but I'm getting the error "No default constructor exists for class 'Ball'"

The Ball.h file :

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <raylib.h>


class Ball {
    private:
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 speed;
        float radius;
    public:
        Ball(Vector3 ballPosition, Vector3 ballSpeed,float ballRadius);       
};
```

The Ball.cpp file :

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include <raymath.h>
#include <rlgl.h>

Ball::Ball(Vector3 position, Vector3 speed,float radius) {
    this->position = position;
    this->speed = speed;
    this->radius = radius;

}
```

The Particles.h file :

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <raylib.h>
#include <Ball.h>

class Particles{
    private:
        std::vector<Ball> particles;
        std::vector<Vector3> velocities;

        float w;
        float c1;
        float c2;

    public:
        Particles(std::vector<Ball> particles, std::vector<Vector3> velocities, float w, float c1, float c2);
};
```

The Particles.cpp file (where the error is):

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include <raymath.h>
#include <rlgl.h>
#include "Particles.h"


Particles::Particles(std::vector<Ball> particles, std::vector<Vector3> velocities, float w, float c1, float c2) {
    this->particles = particles;
    this->velocities = velocities;
    this->w = w;
    this->c1 = c1;
    this->c2 = c2;
}
```

Comment: Putting your code together into an [mre], I [can't replicate any error](https://godbolt.org/z/Pjz1qY8on). There's just no default construction of any `Ball` object anyhwere. Please maker sure to create a proper [mre] to show us, then use it to get the error you ask about, and copy-paste the code as well as the full and complete build output into your question. Also please add a comment on the line where you get the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that since you have a **parameterized constructor** for your class `Ball`, the compiler will **not synthesize** a **default constructor** by itself. So if you want to create/construct an object of class `Ball` using a default constructor, say by writing `Ball b;`, then you **must first provide** a default constrcutor for class `Ball` as shown below.

#### Solution 1

Just add a **default constrctor** in class `Ball` as shown below:

**Ball.h**

```
class Ball {
    private:
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 speed;
        float radius = 0;//use in-class initializer
    public:
        Ball(Vector3 ballPosition, Vector3 ballSpeed,float ballRadius); 
        Ball() = default;   //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR ADDED   
};
```

#### Alternative Method of adding constructor

**Another way** of adding a default constructor would be as shown below:

**Ball.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <raylib.h>


class Ball {
    private:
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 speed;
        float radius = 0;//use IN-CLASS INITIALIZER
    public:
        Ball(Vector3 ballPosition, Vector3 ballSpeed,float ballRadius); 
        Ball(); //declaration for default constrctor      
};
```

**Ball.cpp**

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include <raymath.h>
#include <rlgl.h>

Ball::Ball(Vector3 position, Vector3 speed,float radius) {
    this->position = position;
    this->speed = speed;
    this->radius = radius;

}
//define the default constructor
Ball::Ball()
{
    cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    //do other things here if needed
}
```

Comment: @Sanico: Does a default `Ball` make sense? if yes, which should be its default values?